# How routing to two component? angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have this routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'todos/:id',
        component: TodosComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'todos/:id',
        component: PostsComponent
      }
    ]
  }

];
```

the TodosComponent its working, but the PostsComponent doesn't.
I want that I am routing to 'todos/:id' the two components will open side by side.

Comment: Is the meaning of *open side by side* is open with **multiple browser tabs** or **single page with 2 components**? If **with multiple browser tabs** I don't think that is possible. If **single page with 2 components**, I suggest creating a parent component, then in the parent component what you did is render these 2 (child) components and also from parent component pass the `id` to child components. And your routing should change to point to the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options you can use outlet, which gives you multiple location on a component to render routed components. But since you say side-by-side. I would just do the simple thing and have a parent component. And just have each component within.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the path. The routes are not allowed to be the same because the route that will be first matched, it will be taken, and by your example only the **TodosComponent** will be appeared.